# Progress bar in android widget not animated in real terminals

Tags: android, animation, widget, progress-bar

I'm designing a widget that includes a ProgressBar with my own animation and style.

For that, I define a drawable with a layer-list:

```
refresh_animation_indeterminate.xml:

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <rotate
            android:drawable="@mipmap/ic_refresh"
            android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%"
            android:fromDegrees="72"
            android:toDegrees="1440"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

then a style using this drawable

```
    <style name="WidgetProgressBarStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar">
        <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@drawable/refresh_animation_indeterminate</item>
    </style>
```

and then I use the style in my ProgressBar within the widget

```
        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/widgetProgressBar"
            style="@style/WidgetProgressBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp" />
```

The problem I have is that though the ProgressBar is animated without issues in AVD simulated devices (I tried with a couple of emulated devices using APIs 30 and 24, Pixel 2 XL and Pixel 3a XL), in real terminals simulation does not progress beyond first frame; that is, the icon is stuck at 72 degrees (=fromDegrees). I have tried in two Samsung devices (one with API 30 and another old one with API 24) and a LG with API 28. It is the same in all of them. But working perfectly in emulators in the meantime.

Am I missing something here? Why does it work in emulators but not in real terminals? Is there something I should configure for real terminals? (either in my app or in the terminal)

Thanks a lot in advance! (And sorry if I didn't fill the right information, as this is the first time I post a question here)

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer. I tried in a 4th terminal and there it worked. Issue is related with the windows manager that I use.
In the terminals where I have "Go Launcher", animations in widgets are not working properly, that's why they were not animated. If I use the default windows manager in the device, everything works perfectly and smooth